# How to differentiate between customers from two different domains?

Tags: magento

I want to be able to differentiate between customers coming to my site store from two different domains. For example:

```
local.pruebas.es → from spain
local.pruebas.extra → from extra source.
```

The two domains would both go to my site, but the .extra domain (for example) comes from a marketing campaign.

I think that the solution can be to create an observer, for example:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mycompany_Identifycustomer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkCustomer</method>
                </wpr_identifycustomer>
            </observers>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</global>
```

and in my observer:

```
public function checkCustomer($observer){
    //echo 'this work';exit;
    var_dump( $observer->getControllerAction()->_getRefererUrl());exit;

}
```

But it's a protected method and I can't call it, since the class doesn't inherit from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`.

An example of the definition of the virtual host:

**For local.pruebas.es**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs/local.pruebas.es"
   ServerName local.pruebas.es
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
   SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "1"    
   <Directory "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs/local.pruebas.es">
     AllowOverride All
      Options All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

**For local.pruebas.extra**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs/local.pruebas.es"
   ServerName local.pruebas.extra
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
   SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "1"    
   <Directory "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs/local.pruebas.es">
     AllowOverride All
      Options All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Could someone help me with another approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get request HTTP_REFERER header you should use

```
$observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
```

in your case.

Comment: Hi, this return NULL for my, but i think i find the solution with the serverName with the event <controller_front_init_routers> and the sentence $observer->getFront()->getRequest()->getHttpHost();

Comment: Seems like we have a misunderstanding here. I understood you need identify page from which customer came to your website. I'm still not sure what are you doing and why you haven't created separate store for each domain in magento.

Comment: Hi, i put an example for the configuration of virtual host in my question. can you take a look?

Comment: Configuration of your vhosts is good, but I still don't understand, these 2 domains are supposed to be the same store or different stores? In case id you setup different websites for each domain - your customer will belong to that website where they were registered. See this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work

Comment: in my case, some clients enter the website through a URL and some client through another. so we get diferent commision depending on what url they come fron. the domain local.pruebas.extra is only a redirect to my real site. Later when the customer creates an account i place them in one group or another.

Comment: i think that the solution can be in passing a variable in the definition of the virtual host. For example: SetEnv IS_DOMAIN_ES "1"